# Is it appropriate to add a tag that relates to answers to a question?

Tags: support, faq, tags

Questioners tag questions based upon the context in which they are asking.  They may for instance ask a question about what module could display information in a specific using the module tag.  The answers might very well include the Views module. Is it appropriate to add [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views) to the question?

Does it matter if the tag is added before the question receives the answer? (I believe it should not be added until after an answer includes the Tag, but I would like to hear other opinions on that as well.)

I believe it makes sense to add a [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views) (or any other module that is part of an answer) so that future visitors can reference the question which, in the end, involves using a specific tag, even though the original questioner was not aware of it when they tagged the question.

Answer (score 2):

Tags are for the questions, not the answers a question receive.

If the question is "How do I create a table of data in Drupal?" and the answer suggests to use the Views module, then [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views) should not be added to the question, as the question has nothing to do with the Views module; it is just one of the possible answers.

If you were adding tags basing on the answers, you should add a tag for each different answer given to the question.

[views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views) should not even used by the OP as hint for saying that the OP thinks the Views module could be the solution, or it is the preferred solution.